# I have a jQuery code where opacity goes up as cursor goes down. How do I reverse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
    $(function() {
        var $win = $(window),
            h = 0,
            opacity = 0,
            getWidth = function() {
                h = $win.height();
            };
    
        $win.mousemove(function(e) {
            getWidth();
            opacity = (e.pageY / h);
            console.log(opacity);
            $('#myElement').css('opacity', opacity);
        });
    });
```

```css
     #myElement {
         height: 100px;
         width: 100px;
         background-color: blue;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/791/

When the mouse goes down, the element shows. I want to do the same thing except I want the element to disappear as you scroll down, instead of showing up. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `opacity` is a attribute that can have any value between 0 and 1, you can reverse the behavior by simple changing the following line:

> opacity = (e.pageY/h);

To something like:

> opacity = 1 - (e.pageY/h);

You can check the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/omLmrray/)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that this should do the trick.

```
$(function(){
var $win = $(window),
h = 0,
opacity = 0,
getWidth = function() {
h = $win.height();
};

$win.mousemove(function(e) {
getWidth();
opacity = 1 - (e.pageY/h);
console.log(opacity);
$('#myElement').css('opacity',opacity);
});
});
```